# nameOfClass myObject ((something)someNumber) what does something mean when passing it in a class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

How do I pass `(something)someNumber` in a constructor example: `nameOfClass myObject ((something)someNumber);` what type of constructor should receive it. I saw it in my exam but whatever I tried it said error. I don't know what it is, I hope someone could tell me how to receive the data. The only thing that I don't understand is `(something)`.

```
`something` is not a type
```

Example that was given before.

the `tip` is not given

```
 int main() {
        int n, minuti, kojtip;
        char ime[50];
            cin >> ime;
            cin >> minuti;
            cin >> kojtip; //se vnesuva 0 za POP,1 za RAP i 2 za ROK
            Pesna p(ime,minuti,(tip)kojtip);
            p.pecati();
        return 0;
}
```

Only thing I should do is write the class

Comment: `something` is a type. `somenumber` is being casted to it

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica something is another variable. not a type.

Comment: Without code, that is all one can make of it

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica I tried given an example that was given before

Comment: `tip` is undefined. It should be defined as a type.

Comment: `tip` definitely needs to be a type. Since I assume your task is to complete this code, you have to define this type in someway, probably by writing `using tip = othertype;` or `typedef othertype tip;`. What `othertype` should you have to finde out from the context, I would guess in something like `unsigned` but thats only conjecture.

Comment: I'm asking myself the same thing. In my finals, something like that was given and I failed because I was not able to pass the information in the class.

Comment: @n314159 What if the tip had a defined variable. for example tip=5; What then, or I simply can't do that.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot. I will ask my professor then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment `//se vnesuva 0 za POP,1 za RAP i 2 za ROK` it appears as if the value of `kojtip` can be 0, 1 or 2, which would then represent POP, RAP, and ROK respectively, whatever these would mean in the context of the code.

Therefore, you could create an `enum` as follows:

```
enum tip
{
    POP,
    RAP,
    ROK
}
```

This can then be used as it is used in the next statement.

`Pesna p(ime,minuti,(tip)kojtip);`

Of course, there should a `class Pesna` with a *parameterized constructor* that can accept whatever you are passing.

Comment: This makes the most sense we wear learning about enum too, That makes a lot of sense now. I tried with enum and it works. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing

```
nameOfClass myObject ((something)someNumber);
```

You are actually casting someNumber into a type called something. A simple example would be

```
nameOfClass myObject ((int)someNumber);
```

Where you cast someNumber into an integer. Afterwards the constructor that accepts an integer as its parameter is called (or in your case, a variable of type "something") .

Obviously "something" or "tip" must be a known type so the compiler will be able to cast to it. In your case "something" or "tip" may not have been declared.

Hope this clarifies the problem
LT